# svn copy requires permissions to root of repository

Tags: apache, svn

I am having a svn repository structure in the below format:

```
scm
 -- products
      -- productA
            --vechiles 
      -- productB
```

Here **scm** is the root of the repository and **productA, productB** is under **products** repository which is inturn uder scm repository.  **vechiles** repository is under productA
My SVN **Version** is

```
srikanth@localhost:~$ svn --version
svn, version 1.6.6 (r40053)
   compiled Mar 23 2011, 12:15:08
```

My Apache **dav_svn.conf** file configuration is:

```
<Location /scm>
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /home/srikanth/svnrepo
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "My products Subversion Repository"
        AuthUserFile /home/srikanth/M/data/users.dat
        AuthzSVNAccessFile /home/srikanth/M/data/conf.dat
        Require valid-user
</Location>
```

My **conf.dat file** which is used for SVNAccess is as below,

```
[scm:/products/productA]  
srikanth = rw
```

My Problem is when I try to copy vechiles repository inside productA only as I have access only to productA repo, I am having the below error,
My SVN Copy command goes like this,

```
srikanth@localhost:~$ svn copy http://localhost/scm/products/productA/vechiles http://localhost/scm/products/productA/pvechiles -m "Copied vechiles to pvechiles"
```

Output I am getting is:

```
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to PROPFIND request for '/scm'
```

Request to let me know what's the problem behind this and guide me to proceed further..       Thank you,  Srikanth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a long-standing issue with the SVN client: [issue 3242](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3242). It's logged as fixed in 1.6.13; it's a client-side issue so you'll need to update your client versions.

If you need to support older clients then you can apply the [patch with this message](http://subversion.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=462&dsMessageId=2357123) to your mod-svn-authz on your server. This will permit OPTIONS and PROPFIND requests at the repository root for any authenticated user. AFAIK there's no security risk but the patch was never accepted.

Comment: request you to let me know the process of upgrading to 1.6.13. I had gone through the issue 3242 which you had pointed, but I am really stuck with the process of upgrading any help will be much helpful.      Thank you,

Comment: That depends on your OS / version. You're using Linux? Which distro and version? (You can also just download the source and compile your own, but I prefer to upgrade the OS packages.) Or you could e.g. get a new version on a Windows box, copy the folder, then go back to using 1.6.6 on your Linux machine.

Comment: Actually since you have admin access to the server it might be easiest just to grant yourself full rights to the repository (or create a new admin user with full rights) whenever you hit this problem.